# Mini/electrics problem

Tags: voltage

I have a voltage of 9v output from a solar panel and another 2v from a stepper motor wind mill, if I connect the two together will the output then be 11v?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but the current that you can draw will be the lowest of the currents the two sources can supply.

I have the strong suspicion that your 9V and 2V are *open* voltages (= with no load) that will fall off sharply when you try to draw current.

Note that solar panels are generally specified by their open voltage, and by their shorted current. So a 10V 1A solar panel behaves (more or less) like a 10V source with a 10 Ohm series resistor. The highest amount of power you can draw from it (with a 10 Ohm load) is 5V * 0.5A = 2.5 Watt, ***not*** the 10V * 1A = 10 Watt you might expect from the specs.

And on top of that, the specs are always for direct sunlight in Death Valley, which probably does not match your local conditions.

Comment: I think you should note that they will be 11V if connected in series which doesn't make much sense due to the different current limitations as you mentioned... my first thought was that he was connecting them in parallel which would be a very bad thing!